# Convert Character date/time with am and pm to date/time format

Tags: r, lubridate

I am attempting to convert a character date time to a date/time format using strptime. The data is in MDY_HM (1/29/20 3:43pm).

My code currently looks like this:

```
comp_report_tz$Start_Date_Time <- strptime(comp_report_tz$Start_Date_Time, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p")
```

The output for each observation simply shows: "< POSIXlt >"

I don't receive any errors when executing.

Comment: The format specification has to match the string you're trying to convert. You have a space before "%p" in your format, but no corresponding space in your date. You might have trouble with no leading 0 in your month and hour, although at a glance those seem okay. You've also got hours in 1-12 format (I'm assuming, since you have "pm"), but give the format as 1-23 format

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular ensure that all variables are defined.  Use `dput` for this.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the space before %p. Unfortunately, using striptime I was still having issues. as.POSIXct worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the following changes:

- use `%I` for the hour
- use `%p` for the am/pm.
- ensure that the format pattern is in the precise pattern of the data -- it's not in the question
- you likely want POSIXct, not POSIXlt

thus we use this format

```
as.POSIXct("1/29/20 3:43pm", format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p")
## [1] "2020-01-29 15:43:00 EST"
```